# auto refresh DIV using AJAX and FORM with interval after pressing button

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, refresh, intervals

i have a simple javascript i use to feed a DIV with content from a script using AJAX. This happens only after the user clicks a button. What i want after the user pressed the button (once) and the DIV is filled with de output of the script:

1. disable the button
2. have the DIV to reload the script's output every 5 seconds using AJAX

   < script language="Javascript">

> ```
>  function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
>         var xmlHttpReq = false;
>         var self = this;
>         // Mozilla/Safari
>         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
>             self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
>         }
>         // IE
>         else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
>             self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
>         }
>         self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
>         self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
>         self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
>             if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
>                 updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
>             }
>         }
>         self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
>     }
> ```

```
    function getquerystring() {
        var form = document.forms['f1'];
        var xword = form.xword.value;
        qstr = 'addpost=' + escape(xword);  // NOTE: no '?' before querystring
        return qstr;
    }

    function updatepage(str){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
    }
    </script>
    <form name="f1">
      <input name="xword" type="hidden" value="someword"> 
      <input value="betaling gereed" type="button" name="btn" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("script.php")'></p>
      <div id="result"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: i don't understand the way to make code appear as code. it just doesnt work. now i cannot change it anymore because zak was first. sorry for this

Comment: i think it is readable now... sigh..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `setTimeout()` javascript method as follows:

```
setTimeout ('xmlhttpPost("script.php")', 5000);
```

At the end of your `updatepage()` method, call this.

For example:

```
function updatepage(str){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
    setTimeout ('xmlhttpPost("script.php")', 5000);
    }
```

To disable the button, you will need to add an id attribute to your button tag.  Then you can disable like so:

```
document.getElementById('btn').disable();
```

Comment: any hints on disabling the button after the click? ;-)

Comment: @user2175718, sorry I missed that part of your question.  Just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for JS Time Events?

[w3shools jvascript time events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

```
onclick="setInterval(func(), 5000)"
```

**ok Edit:**

i didnt test it, is to late

```
<input id="loadStuffButton" value="betaling gereed" type="button" name="btn" onclick='setInterval(xmlhttpPost("script.php"), 5000);'></p>

function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
    document.getElementById('loadStuffButton').disabled = true; 
....
}
```

**Edit 2: Test This**
Quick and dirty without Ajax to show how setIntervalworks with 5 ms hehe

```
<form name="f1">
    <input name="xword" type="hidden" value="someword"> 
    <input id="loadStuffButton" value="betaling gereed" type="button" name="btn" onclick='setInterval(function(){xmlhttpPost("script.php")}, 500);'></p>
    <div id="result">
        test

    </div>
</form>
<script>
    i = 1;
    function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
        document.getElementById('loadStuffButton').disabled = true; 
        updatepage(i++);
    }

    function updatepage(str){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: i'm not sure. i've tried onload in combination with settimeout() but that kept refreshing the whole page, not the div.

Comment: thank you for you effort but it's all ok now. can i ask another question?

Answer (score 0):

To repeat the ajax call indefinitely:

```
var refresh = false,
    btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = function(){
    refresh = true;
    this.disable();
    fetchData("script.php");
}

function fetchData(strURL){
    while(refresh){
        setTimeout(xmlhttpPost(strURL), 5000);
    }
}
```

And:

```
<form name="f1">
    <input name="xword" type="hidden" value="someword"> 
    <input value="betaling gereed" type="button" id="btn" name="btn"></p>
    <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```